# Python 2.7: Why regex A|B give me extra element in list

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Say I have a input file which contains the following information:

```
/* Name: David */
/* Age: 30
....
....
/* Name: Ben */
/* Age: 35
....
....
```

I want to extract the name of each person and find out whether there is any information on age. My idea is to use regex to capture the name (David, Ben, etc) and see whether there is "Age" at the second line.

So my regex pattern looks like this:

```
regex = ".+Name ?: (.+) .+\n.+ (Age) ?:.+|.+Name ?: (.+) "
```

Basically I use re.findall(regex, f.read()) to find all the name and "Age" and I get something like this:

```
[('David','Age',''),('Ben','Age','')]
```

If Ben don't have information on age:

```
/* Name: David */
/* Age: 30
....
....
/* Name: Ben */
....
....
....
```

My output will be:

```
[('David','Age',''),('','','Ben')]
```

My question is how am I suppose to get:

```
[[('David','Age'),('Ben','')]
```

Note that I do not know the name of each person inside the file. Also, I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's giving you three elements per tuple is that you have three capture groups, and the reason that it's putting names with no ages into the third element is that they match the third capture group. If you want to signify that the age is optional, you should wrap it in a noncapturing group (`(?:)`) and use `?`, which will give you a final regex of:

```
.+Name ?: (.+)(?:.+\n.+ (Age) ?:.+)?
```

It's the same as yours, but instead of having alternation and three capture groups, I have an optional section and only two, which should give you the result you want.